# Setting state with an array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to replace an initially empty array with an array made by a function using setState in React. I have in my constructor as follows:

```
this.state = {
    sources: []
};
```

This displays the correct array (I tested it with [0,1,2]). However, when I try to setState in a method like so:

```
this.setState({
    sources: [0,1,2]
})
```

it does not work and still displays the empty (or original) array. I understand you cannot mutate an array as state directly in React, but I don't think that's what I'm doing here. Here are some other things I have tried when researching this question, none of which have worked:

```
this.setState({
    sources: [...this.state.sources, 1]
})
```

...

```
this.setState({
    sources: this.state.sources.concat('test')
})
```

...

```
var temp = [0,1,2]
this.setState({
    sources: temp
})
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT** Full code:

```
export class SrcMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            sources: [],
        };

        this.searchSources = this.searchSources.bind(this);
    }

    searchSources() {
    // commented out the actual method to replace with test code
        var temp=[0,1,2];
        console.log(temp); // [0,1,2] so I know the method works
        this.setState({
            sources: temp // etc for the other things i tried
        })
        console.log("this.state.sources: " + this.state.sources); // empty
    }

    render() {
        return(
        // etc...
          <button type="button" onClick={this.searchSources}>Test</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: works here - https://codesandbox.io/s/l7j005yknz

Comment: It should not be `this.state({ sources: [] };` in the constructor, but `this.state = { sources: [] };`

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the method you are calling the setState from

Comment: @Tholle thank you, that was a typo in my question, in the actual code file I have it written correctly

Comment: Alright. Could you include your entire component that has this behavior? It's hard to say what might be wrong from the code currently in your question.

Comment: are you sure you are calling that method ? where is that method ? how are you calling it ? when are you checking to see if `state` has changed ?

Comment: edited to include full test code

Comment: You are trying to access it right after setting state, it does not work that way. `setState` is async.

Comment: @Rikin wow thank you, I had no idea. just tried to call from outside the method and it worked perfectly. thanks so much!!!!!!

Comment: that's exactly why i asked `when are you checking to see if state has changed` . `setState` is async so if you check it right after, you won't see the difference although the changes to the state have been made read more here [async setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working, but you don't take into consideration that `setState` is asynchronous. If you log `this.state` in the callback that can be given as second argument to `setState` it will guarantee it has updated.

```
this.setState({ sources: temp }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.sources);
});
```

Comment: We see the same question nearly everyday. Why does not people use render method to log the state? I hold myself from answering "Use the render method" instead of this callback one :)

Comment: @devserkan I fell for this myself back when I started using React. I think it's better now, but it's not all that obvious from the documentation that it is asynchronous.

Comment: Then, I'm the lucky one I guess :). Yes documentation is not so clear, I think I followed some good tutorials this is why I did not fell into this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example that should work as you describe:

```
class ArrayTest extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      sources: [],
    };
  }

  public render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <div>test: {this.state.sources}</div>
      <button onClick={this._changeValue}>test</button>
       </div>
    );
  }

  private _changeValue = () => this.setState( {sources: [1,5] } );  
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <ArrayTest />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Is there `public` or `private` in JS classes?